# How do I match the type of an expression in a Rust macro?

Tags: macros, rust

This is just pseudocode:

```
macro_rules! attribute {
    $e: expr<f32> => { /* magical float stuff */ };
    $e: expr<i64> => { /* mystical int stuff */ };
};
```

I would like to have a differently expanded macro depending on the type that I passed to the macro.

This is how it would work in C++

```
template <typename T>
struct Attribute{ void operator(T)() {} };

template <>
struct Attribute<float> {
    void operator(float)(float) { /* magical float stuff */ }
};

template <>
struct Attribute<long> {
    void operator()(long) { /* mystical int stuff */ }
}
```

Comment: Macros only dispatch on syntax, traits OTOH can dispatch based on the type. Consider using a trait, or using a trait somehow inside your macro.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Rust macros aren't able to do that. Macros operate at the syntactic level, not at the semantic level. That means that although the compiler knows it has an expression (syntax), it doesn't know what the type of the expression's value (semantic) is at the moment the macro is expanded.

A workaround would be to pass the expected type to the macro:

```
macro_rules! attribute {
    ($e:expr, f32) => { /* magical float stuff */ };
    ($e:expr, i64) => { /* mystical int stuff */ };
}

fn main() {
    attribute!(2 + 2, i64);
}
```

Or, more simply, define multiple macros.

---

If you want to do static (compile-time) dispatch based on the type of an expression, you can use traits. Define a trait with the necessary methods, then implement the trait for the types you need. You can implement a trait for *any* type (including primitives and types from other libraries) if the `impl` block is in the same crate as the trait definition.

```
trait Attribute {
    fn process(&self);
}

impl Attribute for f32 {
    fn process(&self) { /* TODO */ }
}

impl Attribute for i64 {
    fn process(&self) { /* TODO */ }
}

macro_rules! attribute {
    ($e:expr) => { Attribute::process(&$e) };
}

fn main() {
    attribute!(2 + 2);
}
```

Note: You could also write `$e.process()` in the macro's body, but then the macro might call an unrelated `process` method.

Comment: so in this context rust macros are less powerful than c++ templates?

Comment: @Arne if that's the way you want to think of it, then sure. Rust macros and C++ templates are only comparable in broad strokes and have different capabilities. However, both *languages* give you the same ability here, as evidenced by the trait example. My biased opinion is that the Rust version is *better* as you don't need the metaprogramming of a template / macro at all — I'd probably leave off the macro and just call `(2+2).attribute()` in `main`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't need, static or dynamic dispatch, I need the result of it at compile time.

Comment: You can `#[inline]` a function call and compiler will optimize away simple expressions, or alternatively declare a `const` function (these days). `const` traits aren't stable yet, here's the tracking issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792

Answer (score 10):

As already explained, you cannot expand differently depending on the type of an `expr`. But as a workaround, you can use the [`any` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) and try to downcast from the `Any` trait:

```
use std::any::Any;

macro_rules! attribute {
    ( $e:expr ) => {
        if let Some(f) = (&$e as &Any).downcast_ref::<f32>() {
            println!("`{}` is f32.", f);
        } else if let Some(f) = (&$e as &Any).downcast_ref::<f64>() {
            println!("`{}` is f64.", f);
        } else {
            println!("I dunno what is `{:?}` :(", $e);
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    attribute!(0f32);
    attribute!(0f64);
    attribute!(0);
}
```

Displays:

```
`0` is f32.
`0` is f64.
I dunno what is `0` :(
```

Comment: Note that this incurs runtime overhead unless the compiler is able to optimize it away.

Comment: I think it is correct answer. And we actually need to check if compiler is able to eliminate any calls and optimize whole expression.

Answer (score 3):

While all the answers here are correct, I'd like to provide an answer more akin to your C++ version.
Rust provides its own version of templates, generics, and they can be used in the same way you use templates.
So, to define a struct and implement functions for certain types:

```
struct Attribute<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl Attribute<u32> {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{} is a u32", self.value);
    }
}

impl Attribute<f64> {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{} is a f64", self.value);
    }
}

impl Attribute<String> {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{} is a string", self.value);
    }
}
```

We'd use it like that:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Attribute{
        value: 5_u32
    };


    a.call();
}
```

Or simply like this:

```
Attribute{value: 6.5}.call()
```

Sadly, Rust doesn't provide () operator overloading in its stable version. You can still define a macro to do the job:

```
macro_rules! attribute {
    ( $e:expr ) => {
        Attribute{value: $e}.call(); 
    };
}
```

And use it as so:

```
attribute!("Hello World!".to_string());
```

I'd recommend using the trait based approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34214916/13040224), as it doesn't use a struct, but a trait, which is considered better practice. This answer may still be helpful in many situations.