# Is there a way to match the expression's syntactical type in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

As opposed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214136/how-do-i-match-the-type-of-an-expression-in-a-rust-macro), I'd like to match on the syntactic level. E.g. I'd like to do something such as:

```rust
macro_rules! do_x {
    ($x:ident) => {
        $x.do().some().things();
    };
    ($x:ty) => {
        <$x>::singleton().do().some().things();
    };
}
```

Clearly Rust already knows if the token is a type or not, because it errors out when I try to pass a non-type into a macro that's expecting a type. Is there a way to leverage this in the macro matching rules, instead of defining another macro that does the same exact thing as the first one?

Comment: Matching a string of characters depending on whether those string of characters are an identifier or a type is matching on a semantic level, not on a syntactic level. The question you linked answers your question as well. The same workarounds apply.

Comment: @pretzelhammer hm, on second thought, you may be right about that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match the type of an expression in a Rust macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214136/how-do-i-match-the-type-of-an-expression-in-a-rust-macro)